# How to get list of users belongs to a group along with all groups name he belongs to

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

Im using **IGraphServiceClient** related below code to get list of Azure AD users belongs to a particular group.

```
IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage lstOfAdusers = await _graphServiceClient.Groups[GroupName].Members.Request().GetAsync();
```

But user.MemberOf returns null.

How to query to get list of Azure AD users belongs to a particular group along its with "MemberOf" property using **IGraphServiceClient** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **group ID** instead of group name to call this method.

```
IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage lstOfAdusers =  graphServiceClient.Groups["groupID"].Members.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

You need to call another method to get the values of user.memberof.

```
var meberoflist=graphServiceClient.Users["userID"].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: So without "another" call for fetching group details for every single user in the group, is it possible to get "user.memberof" of all individual users while fetching all users for a given user group? to avoid another costly call to graphapi

Comment: @thiru No, I am afraid that we need to call separate method to get the result. And this is reasonable.

Comment: @thiru memberOf will return a list of groups, include directoryRoles.

Comment: Then why "memberOf " property available and it has null value always for every user(though users belongs to multiple groups) in the userlist while fetching userlist for the given group? please clarify.

Comment: @thiru The sdk method is calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/members api. You can find the results by using graph explorer. The User entity in sdk contains a lot properties which are null. Only the properties returned by the api are mapped. Hope it helps.